# Running a Sonar Analysis from the Dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

Is there a way to run a `Sonar 5.1.1` Analysis completely in the Dashboard GUI?

If not what are the steps to run it otherwise? I can't seem to find a document that walks you through the steps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Sonar Server / Dashboard / GUI is just used to display data, not to collect data (this old [blog post](http://www.sonarqube.org/we-had-a-dream-mvn-sonarsonar/) explains the sonar architecture).

To collect data you can use maven, gradle, ant or sonar-runner for other projects. The documentation that guides you is in ... the [sonar documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code) :) - see the child pages, as they explain the details of how to configure the technologies I mentioned above.

I suggest you to also have a read at the [configuration parameters](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) you can pass, as the docs are not super clear about them.

Comment: ok I know I have soner-runner installed. I'll start from there, thanks

Comment: `sonar documentation` is throwing 404 Not Found